# How to test angluar app with node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, testing, automated-tests

Hi guys :) recently i've been learning some angular and node js. I've created something like marketplace using this two. https://github.com/MrRav3n/Angular-Marketplace here is my respository.

I'm writting because i want to start my journey with testing. I've read already some basics tutorials but i still havent found angluar + node.js testing. You know.. i dont want to test node.js and angular separately. Is there posibility to test only angluar.js app (wait for callbacks etc) and by doing it in some way test node.js?
I dont know if i said everything understandable. Sorry for that.

Thanks in advance!

PS. i'm looking for some exaples from web (you can just pass a link or smth) or example with my code (products.service.ts is component i would like to test, server.js is my backend) ^^

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are code samples for your tests? Which tests would you like write (unit-test, integration-test or contract-testing)?

Comment: Ok i know everything already, sorry for bodering